# Quantlib calendar-fetching holiday list of multiple CCY's using a loop

Tags: loops, methods, calendar, quantlib

I am trying to get a list of holiday dates in a array for multiple calendars using quantlib.

While passing the calendar name in `ql.Calendar.holidayList` i am getting an error

> module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'df_calendar'

If a pass a single calendar eg `ql.Calendar.holidayList(TARGET(),startdate,enddate)` then it is returning the holiday list, but it fails if i am passing the calendar list in loop. How can it be done?

```
# **$inputing a dataframe from a csv with columns as 'CCY','Country','Calendar'$**

df_calendar=pd.read_csv('________.csv') 

startdate=ql.Date(1,12,2019)
enddate=ql.Date(31,12,2022)

def ql_to_datetime(d):
    return datetime.date(d.year(), d.month(), d.dayOfMonth())

for x in range(len(df_calendar)):

# df_calendar['Calendar'][x] element has the calander names eg-UnitedStates(),India(),TARGET(),etc

 
    c[df_calendar['CCY'][x]]=list(ql.Calendar.holidayList(ql.df_calendar['Calendar'][x], startdate, enddate))
    print(c)
    a=[]
    for x in range(len(c[df_calendar['CCY'][x]])):
        a[df_calendar['CCY'][x]].append(ql_to_datetime(c[df_calendar['CCY'][x]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, by writing `ql.df_calendar['Calendar'][x]` you want to get `ql.TARGET()` because `df_calendar['Calendar'][x]` is the string "TARGET()" — is that correct?  If so, that's not the correct syntax.  You need to store the string "TARGET" without the parentheses, and then use `getattr(ql, df_calendar['Calendar'][x])()`; the call to `getattr` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)) will give you `ql.TARGET`, and then you'll add the parentheses to call the constructor.

A warning: some of the calendars (e.g. `UnitedStates` in the latest version of QuantLib) don't have a default constructor; for instance, you need to call `ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)` or `ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates. FederalReserve)` to specify the exact calendar.  You'll have to somehow specify the argument in your csv file as well.